# Develop an iPhone app on Windows 7

Tags: iphone, windows

I want to develop an iPhone application on the Windows platform. I have Windows 7 installed on my system. Recently I come to know that we can also make iPhone apps on Windows.

A few days later I installed software to make iPhone app on my window machine but somehow I got a virus. Therefore before taking this step again, I want to know that it is possible to make an iPhone application on Windows 7. If yes then which is the best way to do this?

Comment: at this time i cannot afford to buy mac.

Comment: You just said you could make an iOS app on Windows, now you're asking if you can make an iOS app on Windows?

Comment: No i didn't make iPhone app on window.

Comment: I want to know that what is the safe and secure way to make iPhone app. Because last time when i tried to download a software for iphone app on my window machine, i got a virus thats why i never tried it on my machine again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably aiming for something like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/).

Although development for iDevices should be possible on a Windows machine, the best experience will probably always be on a OSX device.

On a Windows machine you will always have to do some extra work to debug, emulate, etc.

Comment: Note that to publish apps to the App Store a MonoTouch licence costs $399

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget the Monocross: http://www.monocross.net/

Or VS Nomad: http://www.vsnomad.com/